# Installing pandas under python 3.7.3 in debian 9

Tags: debian, python, dpkg

I have a problem installing Pandas under Python 3.7.3 on a MOXA linux computer running Debian 9. It has a Armv7 Cortex-A8 600-1000 MHz processor.

I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt ugrpade
sudo apt install python3-pandas 
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

The last two commands have the following error:

```
python3-pandas : Depends: python3-pandas-lib (>= 0.19.2-5.1) but it is not installable)
```

And:

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
sudo pip3 install pandas -v
```

(to see in running) (takes ages to install, but eventually stops)

I installed every needed package (`numpy`, `matplotlib`, `setuptools`, `pytz`, `python-dateutil`, etc) but I still get errors.

Also it says: `you have held broken packages`. When I googled that, the command to list of actual held packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

It returns nothing, so there are no held packages?

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Output of `uname -a`:
`Linux AAGCloudWatcher 4.4.0-cip #1 Wed Mar 27 13:53:48 CST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: What is the results of `uname -a`? The repository that your arm based version of Debian may not have the package. But please edit your post to include the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: See update message of result `uname -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-pandas-lib), `python3-pandas-lib` is built for `arm` and `arm64` and available in the official `stretch` repositories.

According to your recent update, your system identifies as `armv7l` which would need the `armhf` repository branch from Debian.  It does not appear that `python-pandas` is available for `armhf` in Debian `stretch`, but is built for `jessie` and `buster`.

The `pip` install should attempt to build it for your machine, but there may be some incompatibility that prevents this version from working properly with `armv7l` which could be why it is not included in Debian `stretch`.

Comment: Thank you. So any suggestions how to still get this working? Or is this a lost of time and will pandas never work on armv71?

Comment: @ObservatoryGromme as user GracefulRestart points out there is a version for Buster. Debian Buster will be releasing in the next few weeks. If it is possible you can update to that to get the package you need. If not you will need to change to a distribution that has all the packages you need.

Comment: @kemotep thank you very much for more pointing out to me. i'm really new on all this programming. I will just wait and install the fresh debian 10(buster). Thank you all